# Using variable to set title of button in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to dynamically change the title of a button based on a random choice.
I am receiving the error;

```
'String' does not have a member named 'setTitle'
```

I think this is occurring because the variable is not being recognised as the 'button' I am trying to update the title of, I just have no idea how to fix it.
I have tried making the Array of type UIButton, but this seems to make no difference

```
    var choicesArray = Array(["choiceOne", "choiceTwo", "choiceThree", "choiceFour"])
var randomChoice = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))

@IBOutlet weak var choiceOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceFour: UIButton!

func setLabels() {
    var timesTable = toPass.toInt()
    var answer = timesTable! * multiplier
    var randomChoiceTitle = choicesArray[randomChoice]
    randomChoiceTitle.setTitle(String(answer), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Error is being generated at;

```
randomChoiceTitle.setTitle
```

Comment: Which error? Tell us, you want an answer.

Comment: choicesArray contains four strings. Strings don't respond to setTitle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var choicesArray: [UIButton]! {
    get {
        return [choiceOne, choiceTwo, choiceThree, choiceFour]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the array choicesArray must contain the UIButton references instead of literal strings

```
@IBOutlet weak var choiceOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceFour: UIButton!

let choicesArray = [choiceOne, choiceTwo, choiceThree, choiceFour]
var randomChoice = Int(arc4random_uniform(5))

func setLabels() {
    var timesTable = toPass.toInt()
    var answer = timesTable! * multiplier
    let randomButton = choicesArray[randomChoice]
    randomButton.setTitle(String(answer), forState: .Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

choiceArray should have references to the button and then you can change the title of the buttons..change the choice array to the array containing the buttons.

```
@IBOutlet weak var choiceOne: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceTwo: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceThree: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var choiceFour: UIButton!

//choicearray containing the buttons 1-4
let choicesArray = [choiceOne, choiceTwo, choiceThree, choiceFour]
var randomChoice = Int(arc4random_uniform(5)) 

func setLabels() {
    var timesTable = toPass.toInt()
    var answer = timesTable! * multiplier
    var randomChoiceTitle = choicesArray[randomChoice]
    randomChoiceTitle.setTitle(String(answer), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var choiceOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var choiceFour: UIButton!

    var choicesArray = [UIButton]()  //Create a button type array
    let toPass = "1"
    let multiplier = 0
    let randomChoice = Int(arc4random_uniform(4))  //Change this to 4 because you array have 0 to 3 elements

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        println(randomChoice)
        choicesArray = [choiceOne, choiceTwo, choiceThree, choiceFour]   //add buttons into your array.
        setLabels()

    }

    func setLabels() {
        var timesTable = toPass.toInt()
        var answer = timesTable! * multiplier
        var randomChoiceTitle = choicesArray[randomChoice]
        randomChoiceTitle.setTitle(String(answer), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```